# Can't log into minecraft account when username and password are correct

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I have logged into my Minecraft about 2 days ago without any issues, but today I wanted to log in again to play with my friends and I had a problem. The password and the email are correct, but it says that it is not.

[image: Minecraft screenshot]

I have tried changing my password through the mojang account but no emails came to my email adress, so does that mean that my account does not exist somehow? I just don't get it, someone please help because I really need my Minecraft for my Youtube channel and I really do not want to spend another £18 for another account, my parents just won't let me as I have this account already, someone help please.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Mojang support? To me it looks like someone hacked your account and changed your mail address. If that's the case, you *really* want to contact Mojang as soon as possible to reduce any possible damage to a minimum.

Comment: how do i contact mojang ?

Comment: I went to the minecraft homepage, clicked on "Help" above, then found a "Contact" link below. [Here's the link](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/emails/new?ref=footer). Interestingly, the first thing I see is this: `We're currently performing changes to our account authentication process, this is affecting a large number of players when logging in. In most cases our range of support articles and self help functions will allow you to resolve the issue yourself. Please see our help articles below.` So you might not have been hacked in the first place, which is good.

Comment: You probably don't want to share your email publicly like this. Look out for Minecraft phishing emails.

Answer (score 1):

This is happened to me before.

Try uninstalling it, then install it again. If this does not work. Try and create a new Mojang account (not under the same email) and if this does not work. Contact Mojang and see if they can help.

(When I had this problem, I created a new Mojang account and uninstalled and re-installed minecraft. It worked out fine)

**Edit**: I just got Minecraft and didn't have to pay for another account? I bought minecraft. But it didn't say anything about an account to pay for.

Comment: Thanks for your help but i need my premium account to work i do have another account but thats just for demo and i need the full game, to get another premium account for the full game i would have to pay for it again :/

Comment: That's quite strange, when I bought minecraft. It didn't say anything about paying for an account. Maybe my account came with minecraft, or they changed it in my country. I'll see what it says when I try to make a new account.

Comment: No you misunderstood a minecraft account is basically like buying minecraft, its the same thing and i dont want to pay for it again to get another game basically.